# twig symfony - read jquery inside {{path()}}

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

I have a project using Symfony 3

I'm trying to dynamically generate the following URL with the appropriate parameters

```
http://127.0.0.1/add/{id}/{price}
```

I want to do something like this (it's indented for clarity):

```
window.open(
    "{{ 
         path('add_family'
            , {'id': $(this).data("myid"), 
               'relation': $('#my-select').val()
         }) 
     }}"
);
```

these two instructions are good and give the correct result

- $(this).data("myid")
- $('#my-select').val()

My question is, how can I get them to work inside twig, meaning inside the {{ path() }} function ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do it:

1. From your twig page, create a script and set the link in it.

   ```
   <script>
       var the_link = "{{path("link_name", {'id': "ID", 'relation':  "RELATION"})}}";

       the_link = the_link.replace("ID", $(this).data("myid"));
       //etc
   </script>
   ```
2. Using [FosJsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html)